# Any way to recover a lost Office 2010 product key purchased through HUP?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, product-key

A year ago, I had an internship with Medtronic, where they sold Office 2010 for $10 through the Microsoft Home Use Program (HUP).  I downloaded the install file and they sent the product key to my Medtronic e-mail.  I had saved the product key in a text document, but I must have made a mistake because the text document is blank.  I no longer have access to my Medtronic e-mail.

Do you folks have any ideas on how I can recover this key, or am I SOL?

Comment: **your right to use this software is tied to your company’s continued Software Assurance coverage and your continued employment with that company.** -- http://www.microsofthup.com/bulk/faq.aspx.  IE, if you no longer work there, then you no longer can use the software according to Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

If you still have it installed somewhere, download and run Produkey. It will list your Microsoft keys:

http://download.cnet.com/ProduKey/3000-2094_4-10457063.html